# Cloned litecoin - mweb issue, "bad-txns-vin-empty", getblocktemplate isn't working

Tags: bip, mweb

I've cloned litecoin 0.21, trying to create a new coin. It was running well **until block 1439**. Then, miners stopped working because `getblocktemplate` was returning this:

```
CreateNewBlock: TestBlockValidity failed: bad-txns-vin-empty, Transaction check failed (tx hash 7f77894ebcb3xxxx)
```

In code, it's like this:

```
if (!tx.IsMWEBOnly()) {
   if (tx.vin.empty())
      return state.Invalid(TxValidationResult::TX_CONSENSUS, "bad-txns-vin-empty");
```

I was unable to find the related transaction with getrawtransaction on a node with `-txindex`. Then I modified code to skip the `tx.vin.empty` check. `getblocktemplate` worked, I was able to mine but other nodes rejected it naturally. After that I was able to get the raw transaction:

```
{
  "txid": "7f77894ebcb37xxxx",
  "hash": "7f77894ebcb37xxxx",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 56,
  "vsize": 53,
  "weight": 212,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "ismweb": false,
      "value": 0.00000000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "8 32a71ad39691052a88bxxxxxx",
        "hex": "582032a71ad39691052a88bxxxxx",
        "type": "witness_mweb_hogaddr"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Decoding script gave following results:

```
$ decodescript 582032a71ad39691052axxxxx

{
  "asm": "8 32a71ad3969105xxxxx",
  "type": "witness_mweb_hogaddr",
  "p2sh": "CeRHKxxxxx"
}


$ decodescript 32a71ad39691052a88bfeb9fxxxxx

{
  "asm": "[error]",
  "type": "nonstandard",
  "p2sh": "CaiSWTDxxxxx",
  "segwit": {
    "asm": "0 c0ce9f7xxxxxxxxx",
    "hex": "0020c0cexxxxxxxx",
    "reqSigs": 1,
    "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
    "addresses": [
      "mycoin1qcr8f7ut3gsy022rruydxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "p2sh-segwit": "CcDNqxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Transaction vout says `"ismweb": false` but vin is empty and pubkey is `witness_mweb_hogaddr`, meaning it should be `true` instead?

Could this be a bug? How should I approach this issue? My best guess is editing `chainparams.cpp` and editing mweb activation caused this issue:

```
consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_MWEB].bit = 4;
consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_MWEB].nStartHeight = 0;
consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_MWEB].nTimeoutHeight = 0;
```

Oh also, I'm getting this when sending a tx:

```
$ createrawtransaction "[{\"txid\":\"83e01378c82fe86a0cebb8ad063764xxxxxxx\",\"vout\":0}]" "[{\"mycoin1qjqmp2rssgkp5gdexxxxx\":100.5}]"

0200000001d67e79dd60e5dexxxxxxx


$ signrawtransactionwithwallet 0200000001d67e79dd60e5ded6xxxxxxx

Missing amount for CTxOut(nValue=100000000.00000000, scriptPubKey=0014cb0c40a27192xxxx) (code -3)


$ decodescript 0014cb0c40a27xxxx
￼
{
  "asm": "0 [error]",
  "type": "nonstandard",
  "p2sh": "CNaVj7QRiXN5TYxxxxx",
  "segwit": {
    "asm": "0 23e055958bec23xxxxxxxx",
    "hex": "002023e055958bxxxxxxxxx",
    "reqSigs": 1,
    "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
    "addresses": [
      "mycoin1qy0s9t9vtas3hycvufadz6a9e4lxxxxx"
    ],
    "p2sh-segwit": "CSaK1duFt2Fxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Note that I've tried with 99,999,999 coins (input minus 1 coin) and still getting the same issue so it's not about the huge fee.

And IDK if it's relevant, but some more configurations here from `chainparams.cpp`:

```
consensus.nSubsidyHalvingInterval = 840000;
consensus.BIP16Height = 0;
consensus.BIP34Height = 0;
consensus.BIP34Hash = uint256S("0xfa09d204a83a7xxxxxxxx");
consensus.BIP65Height = 0;
consensus.BIP66Height = 0;
consensus.CSVHeight = 0;
consensus.SegwitHeight = 0;
consensus.MinBIP9WarningHeight = 0; // segwit activation height + miner confirmation window
consensus.powLimit = uint256S("00000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
consensus.nPowTargetTimespan = 3 * 60 * 60; // 3hrs
consensus.nPowTargetSpacing = 1.5 * 60;
consensus.fPowAllowMinDifficultyBlocks = false;
consensus.fPowNoRetargeting = false;
consensus.nRuleChangeActivationThreshold = 6048; // 75% of 8064
consensus.nMinerConfirmationWindow = 480; // nPowTargetTimespan / nPowTargetSpacing * 4
consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].bit = 28;
consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nStartTime = Consensus::BIP9Deployment::NEVER_ACTIVE;
consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nTimeout = Consensus::BIP9Deployment::NO_TIMEOUT;
```

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: apparently it's getting stuck at `nMinerConfirmationWindow * 3`th block. I tried setting DEPLOYMENT_MWEB start height NEVER_ACTIVE but it was still being active. So I just put 99999999 instead and it works now, as a workaround..

Comment: Hi Cagri, I'm voting to close your topic as questions about cryptocurrencies other than Bitcoin and topics concerning the development of altcoins are not on-topic on Bitcoin Stack Exchange.